# On Linux Mint: Docking monitor repeatedly power cycling

Tags: linux, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Linux Mint: Docking monitor repeatedly power cycling](https://superuser.com/questions/331166/on-linux-mint-docking-monitor-repeatedly-power-cycling)

I just installed linux mint on my work laptop, which is connected to a dell docking station. I cannot get the monitor to be detected in Control Panel. The monitor seems to get "woken up" every 5 seconds, only to display "Entering Power-Save mode", then goes back to sleep. So....it seems like the monitor is being pinged by my laptop and keeps trying to initialize a connection, but something is preventing it from doing so. Has anyone else seen something like this? Thanks